# Adicionar imagens no bd usando classes em c#

Tags: c#, sql, classes

eu estou fazendo um projeto que possui classes, como por exemplo,, uma classe Usuario, onde se tem :codigo,nome,senha e foto e se tem o método de inserção de usuario:

```
    public string Inserir()
    {
        return "insert into Usuario(Username,Senha,Foto) values ('" + _username + "','" + _senha + "','" + _vetorImagens + "')";
    }

}
```

}

No formulario de cadastro, eu possuo uma função que pega a imagem escolhida em um open dialog e preenche o picture box :

```
private void CarregaImagem()
    {

        try
        {
            this.Fd1.ShowDialog(this);
            string strFn = this.Fd1.FileName;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFn))
                return;

            this.pbImagem.Image = Image.FromFile(strFn);


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

e depois disso ao clicar no botão de salvar se tem outra função que deveria pegar as informações, salvar nos atributos da minha classe Usuario e por fim salvar no BD:

```
private void btCadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbCsenha.Text != tbSenha.Text)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("As senhas não batem ");
            tbSenha.Clear();
            tbCsenha.Clear();
            tbSenha.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            cUsuario cUs = new cUsuario();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            cUs.VetorImagens = null;
            pbImagem.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            cUs.VetorImagens = ms.ToArray();



            cUs.Username = tbUser.Text;
      cUs.Senha = tbSenha.Text ;





            if (con.Cadastro(cUs.Inserir()) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cadastrado com sucesso");
                tbUser.Clear();
                pbImagem.Image = null;
                tbSenha.Clear();
                tbCsenha.Clear();
                tbUser.Focus();
            }







        }
    }
```

esta função salva a senha e o nome corretamente, porém as fotos sempre ficam com o valor 0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D.
Se alguem puder me ajudar, estou quebrando a cabeça com isso faz um tempo, nunca tinha manipulado imagens num BD, inclusive com classes.

Comment: Você tem que obrigatoriamente salvar as imagens no banco ? não poderia salvar só o caminho ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gabriel, para fazer as inserções, use bibliotecas de acesso dados como Microsoft **Enterprise Library**, Microsoft **Entity Framework**, **Dapper** ou simplesmente o **ADO** puro. No banco de dados, para o campo que guarda a foto use tipo VARBINARY e a propriedade da sua classe um array de bytes *byte[]*.

E para ler as informações da tabela, também será retornado para o campo foto um array de bytes.

Espero que você tenha um caminho a seguir.